# Implementing Redux Store from Scratch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am following a Redux [tutorial series](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-store-from-scratch?course=getting-started-with-redux#/tab-transcript). In that Dan Abramov shows how to create a Redux store from scratch. Here's that piece of code

```
const createStore = (reducer) => {
 let state;
 let listeners = [];

 const getState = () => state;

 const dispatch = (action) => {
   state = reducer(state, action);
   listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
 };

 const subscribe = (listener) => {
   listeners.push(listener);
   return () => {
     listeners = listeners.filter(l => l !== listener());
   };
 };

 dispatch({});

 return {getState, dispatch, subscribe};
}
```

The following line inside the dispatch function is what I am confused about,

```
listeners.forEach(listener => listener());
```

I know that it iterates through all the elements in the listeners array & passes each element to the arrow function.

But what does this do **listener()**

Comment: You're pushing numbers to the `listeners` array and you try to invoke that number as a function.

Comment: Could you explain the line inside the dispatch function.

Comment: You should subscribe to the `store` by using a function. Once you dispatch an `action` all listeners functions are invoked.

Comment: OK got it @Dieterg

Answer (score 0):

`listeners` is an array of functions so `listeners.forEach(listener => listener());` iterates through the listener functions and invokes them with `listener()`.